# AngularJS Cache still not updating

Tags: angularjs, caching

I inherited a site written almost entirely with AngularJS, and I followed the existing method of busting the cache with plenty of success... until now.

The old method that used to work was simply to increment the urlArgs as shown:

[image: app/config.js]
.

I recently made an update and incremented from 2.0.12 to 2.0.13 and it still didn't work as some people were calling support complaining that they couldn't see the updates.

I also added ?v=1 to the end of the require.js:

```
<script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="app/config.js?v=1"></script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Even the most complicated 'cache-busting' techniques seem to boil down to changing the url arguments.

This is the site: http://vet.vrshealth.com